# using SQL to check if a table exists and if does then insert data from a different table?

Tags: c#, sql

```
ALTER PROC spTransferDat
@TableName nvarchar(50)
AS
EXEC('SELECT * FROM ClientGroups INTO [' + @TableName + '] ');




public void SPROC_ExecutionsTransferData()
        {
            string tablename = cboNetChannel.SelectedItem.ToString();
            SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

            //Properly just transfer data to already existing table                
            string Command = "spTransferDat" + "'" + tablename + "'";

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, sqlConnectionCmdString);


            sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlConnectionCmdString.Close();
        }
public void SPROC_ExecutionsTableNaming()
        {
            try
            {
                string tablename = cboNetChannel.SelectedItem.ToString();
                SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

                //Properly Defines the string for naming the table according to the systems naming scheme
                string renameCommand = "EXEC sp_rename 'NetworkAccount', " + "'" + tablename + "'";

                SqlCommand sqlRenameCommand = new SqlCommand(renameCommand, sqlConnectionCmdString);


                sqlConnectionCmdString.Open();

                sqlRenameCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlConnectionCmdString.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception myex)
            {
                DialogResult QAnswer = MessageBox.Show("Table already exist, Do you want to just add data to table", "Data Management",  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                //Check for command
                if (QAnswer == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    //transfer the data to the correct table if table already Exist
                    SPROC_ExecutionsTransferData();
                }
                else if (QAnswer == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

All the SQL statements come back as an error, SQL does not allow duplicate tables naturally so I am trying to call this SQL procedure on the try error handling to add data to a table that already exists if a table is not created.

So what happens is I am copying a table then renaming the table with the sp_rename and if the table does not exist this works but if it exist it will error, so on the error I want to just insert all the data from one table to another but for some reason its not working the SQL procedure keeps saying the INTO statement is a statement error. NEED HELP!! thanks

Comment: Do you need a pure sql answer? Or can you do this through .net?

Comment: @shawn so to confirm - if table doesn't exist - you want to do 'SELECT INTO' and if table exits - you want to do `INSERT INTO` ?

Comment: I am just trying to select * from a table into another table I already have the ability to check if the table exists that happen naturally. So I just need to add all data from this table to the new specified table. but I need to tell it the table name so I using a parameter to capture the table.

Comment: i think pretty confusing to everyone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is correct code:

```
ALTER PROC spTransferDat
@TableName nvarchar(50)
AS
if OBJECT_ID(@TableName) is null
  EXEC('SELECT * INTO [' + @TableName + '] FROM ClientGroups');
else 
  EXEC('insert INTO [' + @TableName + ']  select * FROM ClientGroups');
```

Comment: I get an error saying the table already exists now, instead of just adding the data to the table for some reason

Comment: If the table exist I am not trying to remake it, I am trying to just insert data from a different table to the table that exists

Comment: I have procedure that makes a table, if it don't exist, but if that procedure errors out because it already exists then don't recreate the table just add data into it from another specified table. simple but when im trying to insert data it coming out it exists why im not sure

Comment: the @tablename is the current existing table, that I am trying to add into from the clientgroups table. so whatever is in client groups transfer it into the existing if it exist if not then create a table for the data.. but in this case the table exist so just add data from the clientgroups table

Comment: I have another procedure you don't see, it copies a table then renames it, so it generates tables for data coming from the clientgroups table. so sql can manage groups of clients for my server, if it already created a table for a group then it don't need to create another it just needs to add data to the table that has been already made for the specified group

Comment: I hope that made more sense in what is to take place in the system

Comment: Ok that has worked, one query said zero rows effected the other query I think the second under else has worked it effect one row so its got to be second query that worked LOL!! thanks man you good help

Comment: @shawn I'm glad I could help you :) Don't forget you can also vote for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'someTable')
    -- do something
else
    -- do something else
```

Comment: I already know the table exist through the error of the system, I just want to respond to the error by inserting data from one table to another here ill give you the full code so you can see what I mean cause I could be confusing the situation

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that the syntax you're looking for is more like this:

```
SELECT * INTO table FROM othertable
```